# mysqli_prepare() Rejecting Query and Failing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

My web service executes this code correctly without any errors:

```
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", $id, $pw, $dbName);
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} ";
    $query .= "(id, name, address, telephone) VALUES (";
    $query .= "{$id},'";
    $query .= trim($postData->name) ."','";
    $query .= trim($postData->address) ."','";
    $query .= trim($postData->telephone) ."')";                  
    $queryResult = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

However, attempting the same with prepared statements throws an error:

```
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", $id, $pw, $dbName);
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} ";
    $query .= "(id, name, address, telephone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);

    if ($statement) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'isss', 
            $id, 
            trim($postData->name),
            trim($postData->address),
            trim($postData->telephone));

        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        $queryResult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);    

    }

    // error:
    // mysqli_stmt_get_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given
    // mysqli_prepare fails and returns a false instead of the prepared object
```

Why is `mysqli_prepare()` failing here?

Comment: you cannot use trim() in bind_param. only variables are allowed.  I have a [helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) that would help though

Comment: @YourCommonSense That was the snag. Quite the temperamental function. Thank you.